# Centralized the code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

```
- (void) setTheMap
 {
myMap.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
[myMap setDelegate:self];
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {latitude:myValue  , longitude:myValue };
MKCoordinateSpan span = {latitudeDelta:0.05f , longitudeDelta: 0.05f};
MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord , span};

[myMap setRegion:region];
[self.view addSubview:myMap];

PantryAnnotation *dis = [[PantryAnnotation alloc] init];
dis.coordinate = region.center;
dis.title = row.panName;
dis.subTitle = row.geo_lat;

[myMap addAnnotation:dis];
 }

 - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
 {    MKPinAnnotationView *pview = nil;
if (annotation != myMap.userLocation)
{
    static NSString *defalt = @"Volunteer";
    pview = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[myMap dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defalt];

    if ( pview == nil ) 
        pview = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defalt] autorelease];
    pview.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    pview.canShowCallout = YES;
    pview.animatesDrop = YES;
}
else
{
    [myMap.userLocation setTitle:@"I am Here"];
}
return pview;

 }
```

The above gives me map view with annotation pin. I have to write this code in more than 8 files. Can any one tell me how can I centralized this code ? I mean to create only one class and by object of that class I can add the map in any other view.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the rest of your code is not clear, it is hard to give advice, but you may try to analyze it first;
what is common in these 8 code parts, and what is different?

Then you should figure out if you need to create and hold references to any local variables, lets say your map objects, or something like that. 
If so, then subclassing would be the first choice to look at, 
if not then an Obj-C category would probably do (http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html). P.S: you cannot add member fields with this, only behavior (methods) are allowed.

If you need only objects with little to none behavior other than these, then you may make them plain objects holding the parameters only.

Or even you may use static methods like ( +(void) blahblah; ) just to be short, but dont do it unless you are sure that the behavior is generic in nature...

Well, a soup of advice here, if you provide more info, i can write in one of these directions in more details

good luck!

Comment: thanks for reply... see there is a very simple scenario... I am parsing an xml and getting the different latitudes and longitudes for different user. and click on table row I have to show map location with pin of particular user. All most same functionality is there in other views. I have wrote above code many times to display map so I want to centralize the code so I can call the map class by object and include the same behavior. For parameters , latitude,longitude, frame and users name should be there. If u need more detail then say...

Comment: Then you should create a seperate class for those common stuff, including the map, and then set the parameters (locations info in your case) externally, either during initialization or whenever you parse and get the data in full. This way you write these methods once in your class, and then use instances of it from those 8 or so classes. One thing is, if you create and retain objects inside your class, dont forget to write a proper dealloc for the class. And dont forget to include release for instance variables in your main 8 classes(in their dealloc's).

Comment: thanks... its done... but annotation pin always shows the same location ?

Comment: you may have created single instance variable and share among the classes. Make sure that for each one, you create another object, and set the parameters for that one particular instance.